# how would i change my code to cardLayout

Tags: java, jpanel, cardlayout

```
package garage;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author Jela
 */
public class VehicleParts extends JPanel {

    public VehicleParts() {
        JPanel card0 = new JPanel();
        //card0.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        JPanel card1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel card2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel card3 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel zero = new JLabel("0");
        JLabel one = new JLabel("1");
        JLabel two = new JLabel("2");
        JLabel three = new JLabel("3");

        card0.add(zero);
        card1.add(one);
        card2.add(two);
        card3.add(three);

        card1.setVisible(false);
        card2.setVisible(false);
        card3.setVisible(false);
        card0.setVisible(false);


        JButton buttonZero = new JButton("Repair");
        JButton buttonOne = new JButton("Parts");
        JButton buttonTwo = new JButton("Stock");
        JButton buttonThree = new JButton("Supplier");

        //JButton buttonback = new JButton("Parts");

        buttonZero.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                card0.setVisible(true);
                card1.setVisible(false);// shows card1 when button is clicked                    
                card2.setVisible(false);
                card3.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        buttonOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                card1.setVisible(true);// shows card1 when button is clicked                    
                card2.setVisible(false);
                card3.setVisible(false);
                card0.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        add(buttonZero);
        add(buttonOne);
        add(buttonTwo);
        add(buttonThree);

        add(card0);
        add(card1);
        add(card2);
        add(card3);



    }

}
```

Im not sure how i would change this code into CardLayout. If anyone can give me tips of how i could change it, please tell me. This is not my main class. Ive tried cardlayout, however whenever i use it, i cannot see my buttons anymore.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the buttons are visible using all the cards, you simply divide the panel into two panels - one panel that will contain the buttons, and the other that will contain the cards.

So - your main panel (`VehicleParts`) will have a *`BorderLayout`*.

You add two panels to it. One is the cards panel. It will have a *`CardLayout`*. Make the cards panel reference variable final, so that you can access it from the buttons' event listeners (which are anonymous classes). Although the cards panel itself has a card layout, you add it to your main panel using `BorderLayout.CENTER`.

The other panel is the buttons panel. It can have a `GridLayout`, for example. Add it to the main panel using, perhaps, `BorderLayout.SOUTH` to put it at the bottom.

Add your cards to the *cards* panel. Don't forget to give them names.

Then create the buttons, and in each button's listener, change cards using the `CardLayout.show()` method. Add each button to the *buttons* panel.